# Python jpype.isJVMStarted no attribute

Tags: python, nlp, duckling

I'm running duckling.py to do some entity extractions.

Can someone please advise whats causing the error stated below?

Someone suggested that this resolved the issue for them, but i couldnt get it to install (maybe because i'm using windows??)

"conda install libgcc"

Here is code causing the traceback:

```js
def _start_jvm(self, minimum_heap_size, maximum_heap_size):
  jvm_options = [
    '-Xms{minimum_heap_size}'.format(minimum_heap_size = minimum_heap_size),
    '-Xmx{maximum_heap_size}'.format(maximum_heap_size = maximum_heap_size),
    '-Djava.class.path={classpath}'.format(
      classpath = self._classpath)
  ]
if not jpype.isJVMStarted():
  jpype.startJVM(
    jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(),
    * jvm_options
  )
```

Here is the traceback:

```js
Traceback(most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-5-e568931e00a0>", line 1, in < module > runfile('C:/Users/user/.spyder-py3/chatbot/Outlook/intent finder.py', wdir ='C:/Users/user/.spyder-py3/chatbot/Outlook')

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/user/.spyder-py3/chatbot/Outlook/intent finder.py", line 19, in < module > numbersmodel = Interpreter.load(r 'C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\chatbot\Outlook\numbers\default\model')

File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\chatbot\Outlook\rasa_nlu\model.py", line 276, in load skip_validation)

File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\chatbot\Outlook\rasa_nlu\model.py", line 303, in create model_metadata, ** context)

File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\chatbot\Outlook\rasa_nlu\components.py", line 400, in load_component cached_component, ** context)

File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\chatbot\Outlook\rasa_nlu\registry.py", line 131, in load_component_by_name return component_clz.load(model_dir, metadata, cached_component, ** kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\chatbot\Outlook\rasa_nlu\extractors\duckling_extractor.py", line 194, in load duckling = cls.create_duckling_wrapper(language)

File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\chatbot\Outlook\rasa_nlu\extractors\duckling_extractor.py", line 108, in create_duckling_wrapper return DucklingWrapper(language = language)

File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\chatbot\Outlook\duckling\wrapper.py", line 35, in __init__maximum_heap_size = maximum_heap_size)

File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\chatbot\Outlook\duckling\duckling.py", line 44, in __init__self._start_jvm(minimum_heap_size, maximum_heap_size)

File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\chatbot\Outlook\duckling\duckling.py", line 67, in _start_jvm if not jpype.isJVMStarted():

AttributeError: module 'jpype' has no attribute 'isJVMStarted'
```

Answer (score 0):

So i've finally resolved it and i'll post the answer here in case it helps anyone in the future.

I did have all the required packages installed under my Miniconda directory:

```
AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages
```

However, my PYTHONPATH was only looking at the following path which did NOT have the modules installed:

```
AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
```

So I did an append to resolve it and it worked:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages')
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. I currently have a similar problem, could you please detail which packages for jpype where in your directory?